# Executing same functions for different classes

Tags: java, processing

I'm making something that deals with JSON in processing. The input format is flexible so I need to do the same code for different classes often. Is there any preferred way to do this other that what I've done?

```
Object part = json.get(0);
File saveTo = new File(dataPath("test.txt"));
if (part.getClass() == JSONObject.class)
  ((JSONObject)part).save(saveTo, "");
if (part.getClass() == JSONArray.class)
  ((JSONArray)part).save(saveTo, "");
```

Comment: Why do you need the cast? [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) is a method of `Object`

Comment: Write the code once for an ancestor of all the classes that has the method in question.

Comment: @UnholySheep Well guess that was a bad example. Didn't think about that.

Comment: Not directly an answer (I'd need a better example of what's your real problem), but if you're dealing with JSON a lot I'd strongly recommend having a look at the Jackson library (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). By adding some annotations to Java classes it can automatically encode/decode JSON into Java objects and back.

Comment: @Ede I'm using Processing which has JSON stuff built in. Does that deal well with mixed type stuff and incorrect JSON (like `{a:"b",c:[{"test":hello world}]}`?)

Comment: @Aziuth The JSONObject and JSONArray classes are an extension of Object, which doesn't have the `save()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things:

First off, you should always wrap `if` statements in `{ }` curly brackets.

```
Object part = json.get(0);
File saveTo = new File(dataPath("test.txt"));
if (part.getClass() == JSONObject.class){
  ((JSONObject)part).save(saveTo, "");
}
if (part.getClass() == JSONArray.class){
  ((JSONArray)part).save(saveTo, "");
}
```

Secondly, if you only expect one of those `if` statements to execute, then you should probably use an `else if`:

```
Object part = json.get(0);
File saveTo = new File(dataPath("test.txt"));
if (part.getClass() == JSONObject.class){
  ((JSONObject)part).save(saveTo, "");
}
else if (part.getClass() == JSONArray.class){
  ((JSONArray)part).save(saveTo, "");
}
```

Third, you could use the `instanceof` operator instead of getting the class:

```
Object part = json.get(0);
File saveTo = new File(dataPath("test.txt"));
if (part instanceof JSONObject){
  ((JSONObject)part).save(saveTo, "");
}
else if (part instanceof JSONArray){
  ((JSONArray)part).save(saveTo, "");
}
```

But to answer your question, there isn't a great way to minimize this code, because `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` are both direct subclasses of `Object`. It would be easier if, say, `JSONArray` was a subclass of `JSONObject`, but it's not.

But if you find yourself writing this code in multiple places, you should extract it into a function, like this:

```
void saveJsonThing(Object part, File file)
    if (part instanceof JSONObject){
      ((JSONObject)part).save(saveTo, "");
    }
    else if (part instanceof JSONArray){
      ((JSONArray)part).save(saveTo, "");
    }
    else{
       //handle error?
    }
}
```

Then your code can just call that function whenever it needs to save something:

```
Object part = json.get(0);
File saveTo = new File(dataPath("test.txt"));
saveJsonThing(part, saveTo);
```